# mysql case when in clauses

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sqlyog

I have to check the value of @inv_status with below MySQL code but not getting the desired output.
I am expecting "success 1" but it is giving 0, please suggest.

```
SET @ip_AllocationId = 1;
SET @ip_status = NULL;

SET @inv_status = 4;


SELECT  CASE WHEN @inv_status IN(
SELECT
CASE 
  WHEN @ip_AllocationId = 1 AND ISNULL(@ip_status) THEN (SELECT CONCAT("1",",","4"))
  WHEN @ip_AllocationId = 1 AND @ip_status=1 THEN 1
  WHEN @ip_AllocationId = 1 AND @ip_status=2 THEN 4
  ELSE NULL
 END AS filter
) THEN "1" ELSE "0" END AS "success";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
SET @ip_AllocationId = 1;
SET @ip_status = NULL;
SET @inv_status = 4;

SELECT @inv_status = (
  CASE 
    WHEN @ip_AllocationId = 1 AND @ip_status IS NULL THEN CONCAT('1',',','4')
    WHEN @ip_AllocationId = 1 AND @ip_status=1 THEN 1
    WHEN @ip_AllocationId = 1 AND @ip_status=2 THEN 4
  END
) AS success;
```

What you are doing is compare `@inv_status` to the string `'1,4'` because the boolean expression `@ip_AllocationId = 1 AND @ip_status IS NULL` of the 1st branch of the `CASE` expression is `TRUE`. 
So the result is `FALSE` and you get `0`.
I suspect that you want is something like this:

```
SET @ip_AllocationId = 1;
SET @ip_status = NULL;
SET @inv_status = 4;

SELECT FIND_IN_SET(@inv_status,
  CASE 
    WHEN @ip_AllocationId = 1 AND @ip_status IS NULL THEN CONCAT('1',',','4')
    WHEN @ip_AllocationId = 1 AND @ip_status=1 THEN '1'
    WHEN @ip_AllocationId = 1 AND @ip_status=2 THEN '4'
  END
) > 0 AS success;
```

This way you check the existence of `@inv_status` in a comma separated list of values instead of a straight comparison.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6f0fbc94fac19e3ffec7c3ea0c2f2d55).

Answer (score 0):

The `IN`-comparison operator expects a parameter to be a set, not a string. In your values it returns a set but that set constant single string '1,4' which is not same as 1.